# Transfer value to other page using PHP session - textarea

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

Transfer value to another page was successful, I have read many topics on this subject, stockoverflow really helped me with this.

On the first page (eg page1.php) I have input. Normally I type a value to it.

With php I write in a session variable and after clicking submit I can transfer this value to the other side (eg page2.php) which is a simple contact page. This value is pasted into a textarea field.

My problem is that it takes only the value that I type directly to the input, which is located in page1.php. I wanted to create rather calculator, which will consist of the price according to the entered number of kilograms of product. (the kilogram is the value entered in the input).

How do I get a form field was clean, and the Order the product was all redirected correctly?

My code in page1.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['towar1'] = $cena1;
?>

<form method="get" action="kontakt.php">
<input id="wart1" type="number" value="0" name="towar1" class="ilosc" required>
</form>
```

My code in page2.php(conttact page) :

```
<?php
session_start();
$cena1 = $_GET['towar1'];
?>

<label for="wiadomosc"></label>
<textarea placeholder="" name="wiadomosc" required><?php echo $cena1 ?></textarea>
```

///PROBLEM

when I trying to figure how to get good value of product price (e.g. for 1 kg will be 19$)
i wrote code of this kind directly on my page2.php:

```
<?php echo $cena1*19 ?>
```

But when I do this, any direct entrance on the contact page gives me already written text which is 0 (zero).

Can I avoid that 0? How can I make textarea will be blank always, and my page1.php (calculator) will calculate correct number (const which is 19$ per kilo and number of kilos that you entered in input)

Comment: Why don't you use javascript/jQuery to calculate the price?

Comment: But when i didn't set number of kilos and the js/jQ calculate it otherwise, the 0(zero) will be on output and will be exist on textarea even if I enter the page2.php (my native contanct page) first time and always without entering on my calculator page (page1.php) Sorry for my crazy english - i know it is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite not clear, lets go through this: page1.php contains input that manage Item quantity and $_SESSION variable with its price, on the page 2 you need to display quantity*price_per_item number, right? If yes, try the following approach:

```
<?php
session_start();
$cena1 = $_GET['towar1'] * $_SESSION['towar1'];
?>

<label for="wiadomosc"></label>
<textarea placeholder="" name="wiadomosc" required><?php echo $cena1 ?></textarea>
```

, where $_GET['towar1'] is an items quantity and $_SESSION['towar1'] is an item price.

p.s For more adnvanced technique do not hesitate to ask in comments.

Hope it helps, cheers.

**EDIT**

Considering our converstation in comments I can assume that this approach would helps you:

$cena1 = (!empty($_GET['towar1']) && $_GET['towar1'] != 0 )? $_GET['towar1'] * 19 : '';

This line check if $_GET['towar1'] variable is not empty and not zero. If it match the condition - make calculation, else - return an empty string (not zero).

Please note that everything we're talking about above is not secure and can be abused by end-user. Please consider to review input validation aproach.

Comment: Problem is with 0(zero) appears in textarea when everything is calculating correctly. I know that the 0 appears because kilos is not set by user in input (on page1.php) and the const. ( the price 19$ ) is going crazy because 0*19=0 this is strange for me. But how to fix that 0 will never appears, but only when user click submit on page1.php and wrote some values on kilos input.

Comment: Please clarify it more deeply: page1.php has got a form, that send to the page2.php a QUANTITY value with $_GET['towar1'] variable, right? page2.php contains a calcualtion that should multiply QUANTITY*19, and print it into the textarea as FINAL_PRICE, correct? The question is to prevent 0 (zero) on  QUANTITY*19 when QUANTITY equals to 0 (zero) on page2.php?

Comment: yes exactly, page1 only send QUANTITY value (in page1 i have this $_SESSION['towar1'] = $cena1;). page2 contains simple contanct form, few inputs (name, email, phone) and textarea (which is the place for pasted output of multiply QUANTITY*19).

When I using pure code (I mean without multiply * 19 or any math action) the 0(zero) in textarea DOES NOT APPEAR - so I can say everything is allright, BUT with this option page1 send QUANTITY ONLY to right place (textarea) and nothing more.
Only If page2 got blank textarea field without 0 and count correctly QUANTITY*19 after I send it from page1

Comment: This approach is exactly what I'm talking about :)

I am very grateful for your help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is that you are using sessions wrong.

The workflow of application should be like:

1. user enters the amount
2. you process it, if needed you give an error message or something else
3. save amount to session
4. redirect user to next page
5. calculate price
6. display result

Code example using your code:

Page1 should be:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['wart1'])) {
    $_SESSION['towar1'] = (int) $_GET['wart1'];
    header('Location: page2.php');
}
?>

<form method="get" action="kontakt.php">
<input id="wart1" type="number" value="0" name="towar1" class="ilosc" required>
</form>
```

Page2:

```
<?php
session_start();
$cena1 = $_SESSION['wart1'] * 19;
?>

<label for="wiadomosc"></label>
<textarea placeholder="" name="wiadomosc" required><?php echo $cena1 ?></textarea>
```